# Different behaviour while passing shared_ptr to weak_ptr in thread functions and normal functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

I'm having a thread function which takes a weak_ptr<> and I pass my shared_ptr<> in the thread function.

Legally weak_ptr<> should not increment the reference count of shared_ptr<>, however, unless I typecast with weak_ptr<> while passing the same to the thread function, it increments the reference count (unexpected)

This behaviour happens only with thread functions and not with normal function calls.

Here is the code for thread function

```
void thrdfn(weak_ptr<int> wp) {
    cout<<wp.use_count()<<endl;  // Prints 2
}

int main() {
    shared_ptr<int> sp = make_shared<int>();
    thread th { thrdfn, (sp)};
    th.join();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I typecast while creating thread, it behaves properly

```
void thrdfn(weak_ptr<int> wp) {
    cout<<wp.use_count()<<endl;  // Prints 1
}

int main() {
    thread th { thrdfn, weak_ptr<int>(sp)}; // typecast 
}
```

When I call the function as a normal function call, it works fine without typecasting

```
void thrdfn(weak_ptr<int> wp) {
    cout<<wp.use_count()<<endl;  // Prints 1
}

int main() {
    shared_ptr<int> sp = make_shared<int>();
    thrdfn(sp);
    return 0;
}
```

Behaviour is same with multiple compilers

Answer (score 2):

When you write construct a [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) (and I removed the superfluous parentheses):

```
thread th{thrdfn, sp};
```

What happens is:

> The new thread of execution starts executing
>
> ```
> std::invoke(decay_copy(std::forward<Function>(f)), decay_copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
> ```
>
> where decay_copy is defined as
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v) { return std::forward<T>(v); }
> ```

Which is to say, your `shared_ptr` is copied into the thread and you take a `weak_ptr` off of that copy. So there are two `shared_ptr`s: yours and the `thread`'s.

Comment: The count remains 2 during the lifecycle of the thread, no matter how long it takes.

Comment: @DakshGupta Sorry, wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid trying auto conversion from shared_ptr to weak_ptr, it may create extra shared_ptr. Below snippet should work fine :

```
shared_ptr<int> sp = make_shared<int>();
weak_ptr<int> weak = sp;
thread th { thrdfn, (weak)};
```

Comment: Regarding *why* the copy is made, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread).  *The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with std::ref or std::cref).*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code is no different than typecasting. My intention of the question was to know why this is happening, is there any specification which mandates difference in behaviour

Comment: "but the code is no different than typecasting"> *Neither* what you are doing or what seccpur is suggesting are typecasting.