# Is it ok to call myfunc(make_shared<int>(0)) to a function receiving a weak_prt?

Tags: c++, scope, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-references

I'm having a function that takes a weak_ptr<> and I pass my shared_ptr<> in the function.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void takeweak(std::weak_ptr<int> wp) {
    std::cout << wp.use_count() << std::endl;  // prints 1
}

int main() {
    takeweak(std::make_shared<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Is this working by luck or it is working by design?

Do I have a copy of the shared pointer living throughout the `main()` scope function? Or Will the shared pointer live throughout the scope of `takeweak()` body (up to its stack unwind)?

Is it probable that this behavior going to break in a new version of the compiler or the language standard?

Related question: [Different behaviour while passing shared_ptr to weak_ptr in thread functions and normal functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559601/different-behaviour-while-passing-shared-ptr-to-weak-ptr-in-thread-functions-and)

Comment: The `std::sharded_ptr` (returned by `std::make_shared`) is a temporary and will live until the end of the full expression (the `;` at the end of the line).

Comment: Working by design.  The shared pointer will live until the end of the full expression.  Unlikely that this behavior will break ever.